# Add a toolbar to the left side of the main window in PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtoolbar

I'm building a GUI using Pyside. I'm trying to add a toolbar to the left side of my main window. This code works for adding a toolbar on top:

```
toolbarBox = self.addToolBar('boxAdjustment')
```

However, I want to customize it to locate at the left side. I tried the code below. It doesn't give me an error, but no toolbar shows up.

```
toolbarBox = QtGui.QToolBar('boxAdjustment')
self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea , toolbarBox)
```

"self" is a QMainWindow object in the code snippets above. Do you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to achieve this is

```
toolbarBox = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, toolbarBox)
```

You were close but the argument in `QToolBar(argument)` is actually the parent window, not a string or the toolbar name.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in qt designer?